# Adjective form of trepidation

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Is there such a thing?

I know I can use words like anxious, fearful, etc in its place but none of those words capture the anxiety over the future that trepidation does.

Is there some form of trepidation that works?

Comment: What's wrong with "trepidatious"?

Comment: Closed as too basic, but this page is the top google link when searching this question - which is actually part of the purpose of stackexchange - to be a reference for posterity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"[Trepidatious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trepidatious)" is an adjective form of "trepidation". There is also the simple word "[trepid](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trepid)"

Comment: According to [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trepidatious) it is an adverb. Terpid does not really have to same meaning.

Comment: Read that more carefully. "Trepidatious" is an adj. "Trepidatiously" is also listed, as an adv.

Comment: My apologies, missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Words such as tentative, anxious or fearful would work.

Comment: But none of them express fear for the future, they are more generic.

Comment: The word 'tentative' expresses fear about what will happen; it is directly about the future.

Comment: I thought tentative was more about being unsure. Has nothing to do with the future.

Comment: What are we unsure about?  Mostly.... the future.

Comment: I will not hesitate to add 'hesitant' to the list.

Comment: Still lacks a future component.

Comment: Why do you think that trepidation has '*a future component*'? The definition cited in the accepted answer says of 'trepidation': *A fearful state; a state of hesitation or concern.*

Answer (score 0):

many neologisms can be understood at first glance.
But you risk slowing the reader to think what it must mean, and irritating him.
If conveying your exact meaning is worth that, then coin the word, "trepidatious"

Comment: It's already a word, you don't need to coin it.

Comment: I am looking for a pre-existing word, not to coin a new one. In light of @MarkBeadles's comment, I agree but I need an adjective rather than an adverb.

Comment: @soandos "trepidatious" is a perfectly fine word: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trepidatious It's an adjective.

Comment: I think people have an issue with "trepidatious" because why not just use "trepid"?

Comment: @Julia: 'trepid' is rare and obscure, 'with trepidation' is well understood, and even if 'trepidatious' sounds like a goofy neologism, it is close enough sounding to the well-known phrase to have its meaning easily inferred (you don't get that with 'trepid').